# What's faster $('#parent .childclass1, #parent .childclass2').css(something) or $('#parent').children().css(something)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think the title is explanatory. I'm becoming performance obsessed due to previous problems and am trying to get everything to max speed. As I found out that $('#parent').find('li') is faster than $('#parent li') I feel like I don't know anything anymore... So thus my question:

What's faster

```
$('#parent .childclass1, #parent .childclass2').css(something)
```

or

```
$('#parent').children().css(something)?
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) it yourself and tell us what you learnt ?

Comment: The second, since it throws an exception immediately :) If you meant `.children()`, note that they are functionally different.

Comment: Does jQuery have any `child()` function?

Comment: I couldn't jsperf it as I didn't knew it even existed... and yes I did mean .children() sorry for my mistake...

Comment: `$("#parent").find(".childclass1, .childclass2")` is the fastest. Why? Because the first selector will use `getElementById` which is stupidly fast.

Comment: well actually you're wrong http://jsperf.com/jquery-children-weird-test check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second, as it's only doing one extremely fast dom query, then just referencing a NodeList. As opposed to doing two `document.getElementById` calls then checking all the children if they have a class. The second will be much faster. The first is about [60% slower](http://jsperf.com/comparing) then the second.

Comment: I believe that jQuery will use `getElementsBySelector` for the first query.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-children-weird-test as advised i used jsperf to confirm it

Comment: Oh yes, I just did it too. http://jsperf.com/comparing